# save() method of JPARepository to udate an existing entity in the db. But as soon as save() is called it is deleting the record

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using save() method of JPARepository to update an existing entity in the db. But as soon as save() is called it is deleting the record which is suppose to be get update.

```
DummyBo is pojo for DummyEntity
```

Please refer below  the Table description, using springboot annotations, for DummyEntity

```java
@Table(
    name = DummyEntity.MYTABLE_TABLE,
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint( 
        name = DummyEntity.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT,
        columnNames = { 
            DummyEntity.NAME_COLUMN,
            DummyEntity.VERSION_COLUMN,
            DummyEntity.S_GROUP_ID_COLUMN 
        }
    )
)
```

```
public PNBo updateEntity(DummyBo dummyBo,
    int version, String name, boolean force) {


    DummyEntity dummyEntity = this.repository.findByNameAndValidityEndDateIsNull(name);
    /*
     * DummyEntity dummyEntity =
     * this.repository.findByNameAndVersionAndServiceGroupId(name, version,
     * dummyBo.getServiceGroup());
     */

    if (dummyEntity == null) {
        dummyEntity = new DummyEntity();
    } else {

            List<DummyAndTermEntity> ruleAndTerms = dummyEntity.getRuleAndTerms();
            for (DummyAndTermEntity andTermEntity : ruleAndTerms) {
                andTermEntity.getOrTerms().clear();
            }
            dummyEntity.getRuleAndTerms().clear();
        }
    }

    //setting the fields which need to be update 
    dummyEntity.setName(name);
    dummyEntity.setPartNumbers(dummyBo.getPNumber());
    dummyEntity.setServiceGroupId(dummyBo.getSGroup());
    dummyEntity.setValidityStartDate(dummyBo.getStartDate());
    dummyEntity.setValidityEndDate(dummyBo.getEndDate());


    dummyEntity.setVersion(version);

    //here save method is being called to update the 
    this.repository.save(dummyEntity);
    log.info("Updated successfully!!!Voilaa");
    return this.mapper.DummyEntityToPNBo(dummyEntity);
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code.

Comment: Please add the SQL code JPA is executing after the call to `save`

Comment: I someone asks you do add information to your question it is a good idea to inform them that you did so. This way they'll get a notification about it. For example:"@TimBiegeleisen vaibhav added some code to the question, maybe you want to take another look?"

Comment: @JensSchauder, thanks for educating. I will consider that in practice.

Comment: Can you post please how are relations on your entities defined? (For all of them ideally: DummyEntity, DummyAndTermEntity and the entity from `getOrTerms`.)